# .NET CAS Client Forms Authentication Configuration path="/ApplicationName/" confusion

Tags: .net, attributes, forms-authentication, cas

The [.NET CAS Client wiki](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/.Net+Cas+Client) specifies to set the 'path' attribute to an appropriate path on your server below which the resulting ticket should be applicable.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms
      loginUrl="https://server.example.com/cas/login"
      timeout="30"
      defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"
      cookieless="UseCookies"
      slidingExpiration="true"
      path="/ApplicationName/" />
  </authentication>
  <!-- Other system.web elements here -->
</system.web>
```

My WebApplication name is IntraWeb.

It is installed in D:\WebApps\IntraWeb .

Running on LAN at http://IntraWeb.MyDomain.net

I am a bit confused by the naming. What should I set the path attribute to?

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms
      ...
      path="D:\WebApps\IntraWeb" />
  </authentication>
```

OR

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms
      ...
      path="/IntraWeb/" />
  </authentication>
```

OR

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms
      ...
      path="IntraWeb.MyDomain.net" />
  </authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the logical answer is to set the path attribute to the physical path on the server where your CAS enabled web application root is.

```html
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms
      ...
      path="D:\WebApps\IntraWeb" />
  </authentication>
```

If you want to authenticate the other web applications under your WebApps folder with the same CAS ticket, set the path attribute to

```html
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms
      ...
      path="D:\WebApps" />
  </authentication>
```